# Go's method on struct throws too many argument in call

Tags: function, go, struct

I am getting the following compiler error while running the following Go Code.

```
package sort

type InsertionSort struct {
    Unsorted []int;
}

func (is InsertionSort) Sort(mode string) []int {
    length := len(is.Unsorted);

    funcs := map[string] func(int, int) bool {"method":is.greaterThan};
    if mode == "desc" {
        funcs = map[string] func(int, int) bool {"method":is.lesserThan};
    }

    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        temp := is.Unsorted[i];
        j := i - 1;
        for ; j >=0 && funcs["method"](is.Unsorted[j], temp); j-- {
            is.Unsorted[j + 1] = is.Unsorted[j];
        }
        is.Unsorted[j + 1] = temp;
    }

    return is.Unsorted;
}

func (is InsertionSort) greaterThan (a int, b int) bool {
    return a > b;
}

func (is InsertionSort) lesserThan (a int, b int) bool {
    return a < b;
}
```

and the main package which has the calling function

```
package main

import (
  "learning/Go/testgo/sort"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
    unsort := []int {5, 7, 3, 2 ,4 ,8, 9, 12, 1};
    i := sort.InsertionSort {unsort};

    mode := "asc";
    sorted := i.Sort(mode);
    fmt.Println(sorted);
}
```

Error message returned by the compiler is

> .\sort.go:16: too many arguments in call to i.Sort

Note :-
*Package* ***sort*** *already has another struct called BubbleSort, which has the same Sort method with no arguments. I don't know whether it is conflicting the current struct*.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the method to resolve the conflict?

Comment: @fafl, Yes, I tried that. I replace the function Sort with InSort in both packages (sort & main). It returns the following error. **i.InSort undefined (type sort.InsertionSort has no field or method InSort)**

Comment: The code you posted works. Please post your complete code or this question as it is is off-topic.

Comment: @icza, please refer the following Git link to for the complete code. https://github.com/gokulnathk/Go/tree/master/testgo

Comment: Your code works fine. I didn't get any issue with it.

Comment: @nexus66, Did you tried creating two separate files for *package sort inside the directory sort* and main? Please refer the git link I shared.

Comment: Is it correct your package path? It's like that `learning/Go/testgo/sort` doesn't have your current changes in the code

Comment: @GokulnathK If you use the code you posted, your import should be `"github.com/gokulnathk/Go/sort"`, not `"learning/Go/testgo/sort"`.

Comment: @Motakjuq, Only change is there was a **Go** added in the path after learning. No other changes made with the code. I have made some mistake while cloning the project to my current working machine.

Comment: @icza, I'm having a copy of the same code in my local workstation in this path *"learning/Go/testgo/sort"*. Can't I use that one?

Comment: @GokulnathK Yes, you can, but since the code you posted works, I assume the copy you have in `learning/Go/testgo/sort` is not the same what we see in `github.com/gokulnathk/Go/sort`.

Comment: @GokulnathK look at my [folders tree](https://s11.postimg.org/quc6e4skz/S_lection_021.png). It runs perfectly with this order.

Comment: @GokulnathK You must put your `main.go` into a folder too. Also do you have your `$GOPATH` set properly? What does `go env` print?

Comment: as others have said above, your code works, see it running here https://play.golang.org/p/S1hk9s-p1U, you must have not recompiled with your latest changes.

Comment: @0xor1, I tried that, if it is in a single file. It works. But whenever I moved it to a seperate folder it creates error.

Comment: @nexus66, If I removed the file bubblesort.go from the sort directory. It works fine. But I want both of them to work.

Comment: @GokulnathK i just added the bubblesort.go file and it works again. Do you want i post an answer with explicit order ?

Comment: @nexus66, Could you please post the order change for the files, or send links to the files?

Comment: @GokulnathK check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the order of your directories isn't correct or maybe you've some other oddities.

**Note:** I'm running `Ubuntu 16.04.1 64bit` wihtin `go version go1.6.2 linux/amd64`

So, here are the steps that i used to run your package.

**1-**

Check Your `GOPATH` or export a new one like this example

```
$ export GOPATH=$HOME/Bureau/stack
```

**2-**

Check if your `$GOPATH` points to a directory :

```
$ $GOPATH
bash: /home/nexus/Bureau/stack/ : is a directory
```

**3-**

Clone your [repository](https://github.com/gokulnathk/Go) in `$GOPATH/src` folder

```
$ cd $GOPATH/src
$ git clone https://github.com/gokulnathk/Go
```

Now, the hierarchy of the folders are:

```
$ tree
.
├── Go
│   ├── atm-dispening
│   ├── download
│   │   └── download.go
│   ├── downloadParallel
│   │   └── downloadParallel.go
│   ├── hello
│   │   └── hello.go
│   ├── portserver
│   │   └── simpleport.go
│   ├── safebrowsing
│   ├── testgo
│   │   ├── functionParam.go
│   │   ├── functions.go
│   │   ├── greeting
│   │   │   └── greeting.go
│   │   ├── routine.go
│   │   ├── sort
│   │   │   ├── bubblesort.go
│   │   │   └── insertionsort.go
│   │   ├── sort.go
│   │   ├── sorttest.go
│   │   ├── struct.go
│   │   └── test.go
│   └── webserver
│       ├── modcloth.txt
│       └── simple.go
└── main.go

11 directories, 17 files
```

Here, what we need to know to run your code is:

- Path of sort folder which is : `Go/testgo/sort`
- main.go placed in `$GOPATH/src`

main.go :

```
package main

import (
  "Go/testgo/sort"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
    unsort := []int {5, 7, 3, 2 ,4 ,8, 9, 12, 1};
    i := sort.InsertionSort {unsort};

    mode := "asc";
    sorted:= i.Sort(mode);
    fmt.Println(sorted);
}
```

**Finally**

Check you're in `$GOPATH/src` and run:

```
$ go run main.go
```

output:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 12]
```

Comment: It is working fine. Thanks for the help. Could you please explain what is wrong with my file structure?

Comment: @GokulnathK: create only 1 packager per directory, always keep your packages in GOPATH, and never use relative imports. Read carefully through [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: Good answer @JimB. Thanks.